# Searching type in assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, appdomain

I had an issue that code `Type.GetType(myTypeName)` was returning `null` because assembly with that type is not current executing assembly.

The solution I found for this issue is next:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
Type myType = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                        .Single(t => t.FullName == myTypeName);
```

The problem is that the first run of this code causes exception `"Sequence contains no matching element"`. When I call this part of code again - everything is ok and needed Type is loaded.

Can anyone explain such behavior? Why in the scope of first call no needed assembly/type found?

Comment: Could this be a race condition? Are you requesting the type before it got loaded?

Comment: Yes. This is the reason. What is the best practice to force somehow the loading of assemblies.

Comment: @xwrs I'm not sure, but doesn't [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) help you do that ?

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna. I have references to that assemblies. Why do I have to load them explicitly?

Comment: @xwrs there is a question already on [SO regarding forcing the assembly loading thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384592/c-net-is-there-a-way-to-force-all-referenced-assemblies-to-be-loaded-into-the) hope this helps

Comment: You need to force load them otherwise they will only be loaded when the types that they contain are actually needed in the running code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem you are facing is caused by design of [GetAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) method of `AppDomain` class - according to documentation this method:

> Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain.

So when in your program type fails to be found first time - its assembly isn't obviously loaded by the application yet. And afterwards - when some functionality from assembly that contains type in question had been used - assembly is already loaded, and same code can already find missing type.

Please try loading assemblies directly. Instead of using:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

you can use:

```
List<Assembly> assemblies = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(assembly => Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, but now I see that I have to keep in mind that not all needed assemblies are loaded at the moment

Comment: I don't know which assembly I need and which of them should be loaded.)) I don't know which assembly contains type I need

Comment: Please see my comment above, you need to force load them.

Comment: @xwrs Please see updated answer - I have taken missing part from [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2384608/894174) of Jon Skeet referenced by Justing Harvey.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the type is in an assembly that has not yet been loaded.  Later in your program it then is.  If you look at the output window this should give you sn idea of when the assemblies are being loaded.

Comment: Yes. The reason that assemblies are loading couple of seconds (~5-10). What is the best practice to force somehow the loading of assemblies?

Comment: Yes, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384592/c-net-is-there-a-way-to-force-all-referenced-assemblies-to-be-loaded-into-the

Answer (score 1):

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489661/147511) shows the best way for obtaining (at runtime) a `Type` defined in an `Assembly` that might not be loaded:

```
var T1 = Type.GetType("System.Web.Configuration.IAssemblyCache, " + 
                      "System.Web, " + 
                      "Version=4.0.0.0, " + 
                      "Culture=neutral, " + 
                      "PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
```

As you can see, unfortunately that method requires you to supply the full [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Type` and will not work with any of the [abbreviated forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) of the [assembly name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname(v=vs.110).aspx) that I tried. This somewhat defeats our main purposes here. If you knew that much detail about the assembly, it wouldn't be that much harder to just load it yourself:

```
var T2 = Assembly.Load("System.Web, " + 
                       "Version=4.0.0.0, " + 
                       "Culture=neutral, " + 
                       "PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
                 .GetType("System.Web.Configuration.IAssemblyCache");
```

Although these two examples look similar, they execute very different code paths; note for example, that the latter version calls an *instance* overload on `Assembly.GetType` versus the *static* call `Type.GetType`. Because of this, the second version is probably faster or more efficient. Either way, though, you seem to end up at the following CLR internal method, and with the second argument set to `false`, and this is why *neither method* goes to the trouble of searching for the required assembly on your behalf.

> [System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices]
>   private static RuntimeType **LoadClrTypeWithPartialBindFallback**(
>                     String typeName,
>                     bool partialFallback);

A tiny step forward from these inconveniences would be to instead call this CLR method yourself, but with the `partialFallback` parameter set to **true**. In this mode, the function will accept a truncated version of the `AssemblyQualifiedName` and will *locate and load* the relevant assembly, as necessary:

```
static Func<String, bool, TypeInfo> LoadClrTypeWithPartialBindFallback =
    typeof(RemotingServices)
    .GetMethod("LoadClrTypeWithPartialBindFallback", (BindingFlags)0x28)
    .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<String, bool, TypeInfo>))
    as Func<String, bool, TypeInfo>;

// ...

var T3 = LoadClrTypeWithPartialBindFallback(
            "System.Web.Configuration.IAssemblyCache, System.Web",
            true);    //  <-- enables searching for the assembly
```

This works as shown, and also continues to support specifying the full `AssemblyQualifiedName` as in the earlier examples. This is a small improvement, but it's still not a fully unqualified namespace search, because you do still have to specify the short name of the assembly, even if it might be deduced from the namespace that appears in the type name itself.

Answer (score 0):

And if you exlucde mscorlib assembly?? , you can try this:

```
  var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(asb=>!asb.FullName.StartsWith("mscorlib")).ToList();

Type myType = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                        .Single(t => t.FullName == myTypeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW if you *do* know the `FullName` of the assembly containing the type (or an assembly containing a `TypeForwardedToAttribute` for the type) you *can* use  `Type.GetType`. Specifically, `Type.GetType(Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assembly.FullName, myTypeName))` which will look something like:

```
Type.GetType("Some.Complete.Namespace.myTypeName, Some.Assembly.Name, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ffffffffffffffff");
```

This *will load* the assembly if it is not already, assuming the framework can resolve the location of the assembly.

Here's my sample LinqPad query confirming the parenthetic `TypeForwardedToAttribute` remark:

```
var u = (from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
         let t = a.GetType("System.Lazy`2")
         where t != null
         select t).FirstOrDefault();
(u?.AssemblyQualifiedName).Dump();
u = Type.GetType("System.Lazy`2, System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
(u?.AssemblyQualifiedName).Dump();
```

Output:

> *null*
>   System.Lazy`2, System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089