# Loading modules from all assemblies with Ninject and wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, ninject

I use this [article](http://www.alphablog.org/2012/05/07/simple-plugin-system-based-on-ninject-and-mvvm-light-2/) and created multiply class libraries in project.  I wanted to load all the modules in a Kernel.

for load all modules, I use this code in MainViewModel

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    Plugins = kernel.GetAll<PluginBase>().ToList();
}
```

But don't load Modules(plugin) in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`

Comment: ok. And what's the question?

Comment: Don't load my modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code for load assemblies.I found it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384679/970404).

```
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
var loadedPaths = loadedAssemblies.Select(a => a.Location).ToArray();

var referencedPaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll");
var toLoad = referencedPaths.Where(r => !loadedPaths.Contains(r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
toLoad.ForEach(path => loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path))));
```