# ASP.NET MVC Find class by class attribute value using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, attributes

I have a class with a custom attribute that has a string parameter.

```
[ANAttribute("Ampe21")]
public class ClassB : ClassA
{

}
```

I have different action names defined for different classes.

What I want is to obtain the namespace of `ClassB` or obtain the type of `ClassB` by searching the entire application after `Ampe21`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search all the loaded assemblies like this:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany
    (x => x.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<ANAttribute>() != null &&
                    t.GetCustomAttribute<ANAttribute>().YourProperty == "Ampe21")
    );

foreach (var type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.Namespace);
}
```

You can avoid calling `GetCustomAttribute` twice by introducing a local variable.

If your assembly is not yet loaded, this will skip the assembly. You may load it using `Assembly.Load` but not recommended.

Comment: It seems to work partially. It finds all my classes from namespace `A.B.C` but it doesn't find the ones from `A.Controllers`. Any idea why? I was thinking that assembly must be loaded manually but I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: I've just tried to apply an attribute on a class from another namespace that is not contained in controller and it works... But still, I cannot apply it on controller

Comment: I've just found the problem. I was doing something completely wrong. By using the piece of code that Sriram provided it was working for classes but in my controller I applied the attribute on methods so this is the reason why it was partially working.

Comment: @tzortzik It is not a good idea to load manually. You may get your [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384592/c-net-is-there-a-way-to-force-all-referenced-assemblies-to-be-loaded-into-the)

Comment: @tzortzik Am glad that you found the issue.