# Assembly unable to detect 1 or 2 referenced project assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-assembly, project-reference

I have a reference to a project here named `SocialMedia.Infrastructure` which in turn is depended on `SocialMedia.Core`.  When running a command to get referenced assemblies like this

```cs
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

It's unable to detected the assembly for `SocialMedia.Infrastructure` but it is detecting  `SocialMedia.Core` any reasons to why this is happening?

[image: Here is any image which should clarify things]

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think it only shows them if they've been used.

Comment: You are right, I tried using Infrastructure and it popped up. Any way I can tell it to always include the assembly?

Comment: I tried to do it one time but I don't think I ever found a good way. There are some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384592/is-there-a-way-to-force-all-referenced-assemblies-to-be-loaded-into-the-app-doma)